# Characterization of Selmer group in terms of two descent

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

This question is about p 337 of Silverman's book ''The arithmetic of elliptic curves'', p 337, [http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Elowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf).

Let $E:y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$ and $E':Y^2=x^3-2aX^2+(a^2-4b)X$, $\phi : E \to E'$ be a map given by $\phi(x,y)=\left(y^2/x^2,\frac{y(b-x^2)}{x^2} \right)$. For each $d \in K^\times$, let $C_d : dω^2=d^2-2adz^2+(a^2-4b)z^4$

$5$-th line from the bottom, the book reads
$$\operatorname{Sel}^\phi(E/K)\cong \{d \in K(S,2)\mid C_d(K_v)\neq \emptyset ,\forall v \in S\},$$ where $S$ is set of bad places, $$S=M_K^\infty \cup \{v \in M_K^0 : v(2)\neq 0,v(b)\neq 0, v(a^2-4b)\neq 0 \}$$ without explanations.

Why does this isomorphism hold?

I understand $\operatorname{Sel}^\phi(E/K) \subset H^1(G_K, E[\phi];S)\cong K(S,2)$,

where $K(S,2):=\{b \in K^{\times}/{K^{\times}}^2 \mid v(b) \equiv 0\bmod2,\forall b \in S \}$.

Selmer group should have local rational points everywhere, so $C_d(K_v)\neq \emptyset$ for all places $v$ of $K$.
I don't understand why $C_d(K_v)\neq \emptyset$ for all $v \notin S$.

P.S

If I could prove $C_d(K_v)\neq \emptyset$ for all $v \notin S$, $$\operatorname{Sel}^\phi(E/K)\cong \{d \in K(S,2)\mid C_d(K_v)\neq \emptyset, \forall v \in M_K\}$$ ($M_K$ denotes all places of $K$) $=\{d \in K(S,2)\mid C_d(K_v)\neq \emptyset ,\forall v \in S\}$, thus the proof is complete.

Comment: At all places outside $S$ the curve has good reduction and they are not above $2$ or $\infty$. Therefore the local condition imposed on elements in the Selmer group for $E[\phi]$ is the same as being unramified. And that condition is the same as for elements in $K^\times$ modulo squares to have even valuation. In other words to be in $K(S,2)$ is the same as satisfying $C(K_v)$ for all $v\not \in S$.

Comment: I worry whether $C_d(K_v)\neq 0 $ for $v \notin S$, to prove the isomorphism in my question. But in this specific case, $C_d$ is a genus one curve thus reduction at $v \notin S$ recovers $K_v$ rational point from rational points on finite field ?

Comment: That is precisely what I meant. (Sorry for missing out the "$\neq 0$" after "$C(K_v)$" in my previous comment). This is Corollary 4.4 whose proof is the main part of the proof of Theorem 4.2 in that section.